# P4PASSWD not working in perforce command line

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have setup some environment variables for my perforce, like P4PORT, it's working, I also export the P4PASSWD and can see it if I type `$`export -p, but the p4 still ask me to type in the password when I tried to log in with `$` p4 -u myusername login. Any idea or solutions?

moreover, I noticed some comments within company's wiki, like "If you have automation that requires Perforce interaction and the requirements have not been communicated to the Perforce team, please send them an e-mail. Once the team becomes aware of all the details, Perforce tickets can be used to allow the automated interaction."

does that mean P4PASSWD is not allowed in my current repository and if I want to automate this, I need to use "perforce tickets" mechanism?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the server can be configured to support only ticket-based authentication, by setting the security configuration to level 3 or higher, and yes, it sounds like that's what's happening in your case, and yes, you should use the tickets authentication for your automation.

Comment: @BryanPendleton thanks a lot, I think the problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some research and seems got a valid solution, the solution is generating a global ticket, `$ p4 login -a -p`, this will print out a long string of characters, store it some where, for example, `~/.myp4ticket`, then you can type `` $ p4 -P `cat ~/.myp4ticket` sync ``, cheers.

Comment: The simpler way to do this is to just run regular `p4 login`.  This will automatically store the ticket in a tickets file that the client will automatically know how to read, so you don't need to put it in a file yourself and then tell the client where it is.